# Power of t-test for aggregate data

Tags: t-test, statistical-power, aggregation

I have data that have been aggregated with unknown variance into a number of composite averages. These data are generated from pooled assays, such as HIV viral load in a composite of 10 vials of blood, or cystic fibrosis protein concentration in a composite of 10 0.01cc biopsies of lung tissue. We have treated and controlled groups and are interested in testing whether there is a difference. We must calculate power based on preliminary results (known effect size/hypothesized mean difference) to justify assay costs and find the most cost-effective aggregation level (e.g. 10 samples per assay vs. 20 samples per assay).

For the primary analysis, we will just use a t-test to determine if there are differences in the endpoint between groups. As I said, we do not have an estimate of the individual level variance in each composite, so inverse variance weighting is not an option. However, we do know how many samples were in the composite, so we can use frequency weighting.

How do I calculate the non-centrality parameter for the t-test test statistic with unknown variance? Also, what are the effective degrees of freedom? Note simulation is not an option, I need the exact distribution of the test statistic in order to use optimization routines to find maximum power under a fixed cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually straightforward. The power advantage of creating composite samples is gained by reducing variability of sample estimates and improving the small sample approximations to normal curves. For $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ having $\sqrt{n} \left( \bar{X} - \mu_x \right) \rightarrow_d \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \sigma^2 \right)$, the vector of composites of size $d$ is defined by $U_i = \sum_{(d-1)i+i}^{di} X_i / d$ and likewise for the second sample, $\vec{Y}$ and composites $\vec{V}$. We then have that the composites are independent samples with $\sqrt{n} \left( \bar{U} - \mu_x \right) \rightarrow_d \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \sigma^2/d \right)$ and likewise for $\vec{V}$.

So you can just calculated the pooled variance, the reduced effective degrees of freedom based on the fewer observed samples, and *voilà* that's all there is to it.